# Multiple Robotino co-ordination

Tags: navigation, roslaunch, robotino, gmapping, librviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am new to ROS and just I have just managed to install and run the robotino-ros-pkg in my ubuntu VM. I am working on multiple robotinos and I needed to create a static map for them to run in. I was following the [gmapping tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/robotino_navigation/Tutorials/Mapping%20with%20Robotino) and I was able to launch all the nodes, and also open rviz successfully. But before launching rviz I get the following of errors in the gmapping launch terminal

*libGL error: pci id for fd 24: 80ee:beef, driver (null)*

*OpenGL Warning: Failed to connect to host. Make sure 3D acceleration is enabled for this VM.*

*libGL error: core dri or dri2 extension not found*

*libGL error: failed to load driver: vboxvideo*

Inspite of these errors rviz opens up but I am not able to move the robotino around with the keyboard as suggested in the tutorial.

The RobotModel section in the Displays Menu has error status but I do not have enough points to make an upload, but all the subsections inside RobotModel are marked in red and the following message is displayed alongside

**anglebracketusb_link No transform from [anglebracketusb_link] to [map]**

**base_link No transform from [base_link] to [map]**

and so on for command_bridge_link, kinect_link etc.

I need to create a static map with static obstacles and targets to create a co-ordination mechanism between the two robotinos, any kind of guidance is appreciated.Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/235681/multiple-robotino-co-ordination/) by [Karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/26928/karthik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2016-05-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Fixed after Ubuntu upgrade. All the errors disappeared. Robotino movement only possible when the terminal running teleop node launch is on top

---

Originally posted by [Karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/26928/karthik/) with karma: 18 on 2016-06-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0